# How to adjust my UIButton to maintain the aspect ratio

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uibutton, avcapturesession

I have made a View Controller on my storyboard and added to buttons to it,

I am starting a AVCaptureSession on my View Controller's view like this,

```
AVCaptureSession *session = [[AVCaptureSession alloc] init];
session.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPresetMedium;

CALayer *viewLayer = self.view.layer;
NSLog(@"viewLayer = %@", viewLayer);
AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer *captureVideoPreviewLayer = [[AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer alloc] initWithSession:session];

captureVideoPreviewLayer.frame = self.view.layer.bounds;
[self.view.layer addSublayer: captureVideoPreviewLayer];

AVCaptureDevice *device = [AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];

NSError *error = nil;
AVCaptureDeviceInput *input = [AVCaptureDeviceInput deviceInputWithDevice:device error:&error];
if (!input) {
    // Handle the error appropriately.
    NSLog(@"ERROR: trying to open camera: %@", error);
}
[session addInput:input];

[session startRunning];
stillImageOutput = [[AVCaptureStillImageOutput alloc] init];
NSDictionary *outputSettings = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys: AVVideoCodecJPEG, AVVideoCodecKey, nil];
[stillImageOutput setOutputSettings:outputSettings];

[session addOutput:stillImageOutput];
```

My problem is that my buttons get hidden as the preview layer takes up the whole screen I want the preview layer to assume whole screen but also want to display the buttons for capturing and closing the session

How can I go about it?

Answer (score 0):

Try moving your button on top of the view controller views hierarchy with:

```
[self.view sendSubviewToFront:button];
```

Do it after you've added captureVideoPreviewLayer as sublayer.